# database normalization

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, database-design, normalization

**EDIT**:
Would it be a good idea to just keep it all under 1 big table and have a flag that differentiates the different forms?

I have to build a site with 5 forms, maybe more. so far the fields for the forms are the following:

[image: http://i56.tinypic.com/25it7c7.jpg]

What would be the best approach to normalize this design?

I was thinking about splitting "Personal Details" into 3 different tables: 
[image: http://i53.tinypic.com/auts2h.jpg]

and then reference them from the others with an ID...

Would that make sense? It looks like I'll end up with lots of relationships...

Comment: Is this a homework question? Not a problem if it is but you should mention it in your question (not tags). Back to your question: You say you are thinking of splitting the "Personal Details" in to 3 tables but you do not show a table with that name in your table diagram. You table diagram also does not show the full column names so it is hard to see if they can be normalised. Finally, have you actually followed the rules of normalisation and got stuck or are you simply asking others to do all the work? I think you need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I realise now your mention of "Personal Details" is a stab at normalising that part of the design by extracting the personal details.

Comment: yeah sorry that's what I meant... So now I've added a reference to both UserContactDetails and UserPersonalDetails on UserDetails, and removed all the "personal details" from the rest of the tables.

Comment: Some comments on your new tables: How will you store more than one email address for a user? If a user has two mobile phone numbers you will have two rows in UserContactDetails with all other fields empty. Why is a user's age stored in a separate table from their other details, will a user have more than one age?

Comment: If you've not done so already I would have a read of the wiki pages on normal forms and see if you can apply them to your table design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: by design, a user can only have 1 email address and 1 mobile phone number. Regarding Age: It's stored in a separate table because not all the forms require it (Newsletter or Career tables don't have it, as you can see in the first diagram), so I thought about adding it to a separate table.

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, now UserDetails reference the other 2 Details table if needed

Comment: Normalisation should not be performed based on which "forms" of your application need the information. E.g. would a row in UserDetails reference more than one row in UserPersonalDetails? If so you have repeated information in the Age field. If there will only be one row per UserDetails those fields could be moved in to the UserDetails table.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to just keep it all under 1 big table and have a flag that differentiates the different forms?

Comment: In a word: No. Maybe you need more help than you can reasonably expect from StackOverflow. If you don't have experience designing databases then you would be well advised to hire someone else to work on this. Good database design has nothing to do with forms or user interfaces. Unless and until you understand the fundamentals of what you are doing then you are not likely to have much success with this.

Comment: @user441365 : If you are still having trouble with your database design an article which might be of interest was featured in SQL Server Central's email today: *An Introduction to Database Design* (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Design/72054/)
I think you have to register to read the articles but it's free and a useful site.

Answer (score 2):

Normalized data essentially means that the same data is not stored multiple times in multiple places. For example, instead of storing the customer contact info with an order, the customer ID is stored with the order and the customer's contact information is 'related' to the order. When the customer's phone number is updated, there is only one place the phone number needs to be updated (the customer table) and all the orders will have the correct information without being updated. Each piece of data exists in one, and only one, place. This is normalized data.

So, to answer your question: no, you will not make your database structure more normalized by breaking up a large table as you described.

The reason to break up a single table into multiple tables is usually to create a one to many relationship. For example, one person might have multiple e-mail addresses. Or multiple physical addresses. Another common reason for breaking up tables is to make systems modular, so that tables can be created that join to existing tables without modifying the existing tables.

Breaking one big table into multiple little tables, with a one to one relationship between them, doesn't make the data any more normalized, it just makes your queries more of a pain to write.* And you don't want to structure your database design around interfaces (forms) unless there is a good reason. There usually isn't.

*Although there are sometimes good reasons to break up big tables and create one to one relationships, normalization isn't one of them.

Comment: Your statement "A single table is, by definition, normalized." is not correct. Consider the table shown in the example here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_across_columns) it is a single table but does not even conform to 1NF.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to provide an overview (since the poster seems new to the idea) and made way too broad of a statement. I updated my answer.